# Matlab Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1."2"

Tags: matlab

I keep getting this error:

> Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The
>   valid range is 1-1."2".

My desired output is to get

```
abs(I(2,ii(a))-I(2,ii(a)-1)
```

so that when `ii(a)=2`, I want `I(2,2)` minus `I(2,1)` which is 5.1 minus 5.0

The error is due to this line:

```
  arr(1,ii(a)) = arr(1,ii(a)) + abs(I(2,ii(a))-I(2,ii(a)-1));.
```

I define I as the following in .mat file:

```
save data -v7.3 'I'
load('data.mat','I');
I =

Columns 1 through 6

     0    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    
5.0000    5.1000    5.2000    5.2000    5.5000
```

The code:

```
function arr= fcn(I,count,oldval)

persistent integ_signal
if isempty( integ_signal)
  integ_signal=zeros(1,5)
end
persistent a
if isempty(a)
 a=zeros(1)
end


 arr=zeros(1,5);
ii=zeros(1,5);
aa=zeros(2,5);
 integ_signal=oldval; 
 coder.extrinsic('load');
 aa=load('data.mat','I');



 if count==1
     a=1;
    ii(a)=count;
   integ_signal(1,ii(a)) = 10; % Initial Condition
end

if count ~= 1
    a=count;
    ii(a)=count;
   integ_signal(1,ii(a))=  integ_signal(1, ii(a)-1); 
   arr(1,ii(a)) = integ_signal(1,ii(a));
  arr(1,ii(a)) = arr(1,ii(a)) + abs(aa(2,ii(a))-aa(2,ii(a)-1));
end
a = a + 1;

end
```

Comment: What's wrong with accessing row 2 of variable I?

Comment: You should probably post a bit more of the code - the error might be elsewhere. Also if you debug (breakpoint at that line) then try these in the command line: `a`, `ii(a)`, `size(ii)` and `size(I)`

Comment: Hi Dan, alright, i have updated the code in the above post as the space is limited here, thanks